# jq not working with key including dash

Tags: syntax, jq

I have a REST API, which returns something like this:

```
{
  "foo": 1,
  "bar": 2,
  "foo-bar": 3
}
```

when I do `http /endpoint/url | jq '.foo-bar', it gave the following error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): null (null) and boolean (true) cannot be subtracted
```

it looks like `jq` thinks I'm trying to do arithmetic operation with `foo-bar`.

How do I correctly form this kind of path? Or this is a bug of jq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON text, JSON keys are *always* double-quoted. Perhaps your REST API was formatting it properly in double-quotes and your example in your last edit was incorrect. Because without the same `jq` cannot parse the syntax as a valid JSON.

As far the issue you are seeing, you need to put the field within quotes to let `jq` know that it is a single field `foo-bar` you are accessing and not as separate fields

```
jq '."foo-bar"'
```

Or more specifically use the array access operator as `jq '.["foo-bar"]'`

Comment: `.foo-bar` is parsed as `.foo - bar` so if there is no function named bar, an error condition will be raised with the message " bar/0 is not defined ..."